# Comparing element from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
       id1 id2                 date  id3 ...               sn used   val related_id2
0      348   2  01/01/0001 00:00:00  68  ...  356306054815429    0  2.26           1
1      348   3  01/01/0001 00:00:00  70  ...  356306054815429    0  2.26           2
2      348   1  01/01/0001 00:00:00  69  ...  356306054815429    0  2.26         NaN
3      348   4  01/01/0001 00:00:00  10  ...  356306054815429    0  2.26           3
4      348   5  01/01/0001 00:00:00  20  ...  356306054815429    0  2.26           4
```

And I would need to make the following comparative (better to understand with the following example instead of explanation)

```
For row 0: is id3 of the row where id2=related_id2 =  id3 of row 0 (is 69=68?)
For row 1: is id3 of the row where id2=related_id2 =  id3 of row 1 (is 70=68?) (is 68=70?)
For row 2: is id3 of the row where id2=related_id2 =  id3 of row 2 (is 70=68?)(is NaN=69?)
For row 3: is id3 of the row where id2=related_id2 =  id3 of row 3 (is 70=68?)(is 70=10?)
For row 4: is id3 of the row where id2=related_id2 =  id3 of row 4 (is 70=68?)(is 10=20?)
```

This could be done with 2 loops, but I think panda will have a better performance way to di it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id2': [2,3,1,4,5], 'id3':[68,70,69,10,20], 'id2_related':[1,2,np.nan,3,4]})
df = df.set_index('id2')
idx = df.loc[:,'id2_related']
```

and the condition will be:

```
df.loc[:,'id3'].values == df.loc[idx,'id3'].values
```